# Is there a way to re-bake only the end part of an existing bake?

Tags: animation, workflow, physics, baking

I'm trying to do some physics based animation, and of course the longer the animation gets, the longer it takes to bake.
However, I don't need to keep recalculating the first parts of the animation, as they stay the same.

Is there a way re-bake the part of a simulation after a specified frame, without re-baking the whole thing?

Currently I'm using rigid body and cloth physics.